# Sum of Amount Based on Quantity

Tags: oracle, plsql, aggregate-functions

I want to have two tables and based on the total count need to charge the amount.

```
create table AMOUNT (NUM_START NUMBER(15), NUM_END NUMBER(15), AMOUNT NUMBER(15,2));
INSERT INTO AMOUNT VALUES (1,25000,0.15);
INSERT INTO AMOUNT VALUES (25001,50000,0.10);
INSERT INTO AMOUNT VALUES (50001,100000,0.05);

CREATE TABLE PO (ID NUMBER(10), PO_NUM NUMBER (10), CNT NUMBER(10));
INSERT INTO PO VALUES (10,111,100);
INSERT INTO PO VALUES (10,222,500);
INSERT INTO PO VALUES (10,333,25000);
INSERT INTO PO VALUES (20,111,100);
INSERT INTO PO VALUES (20,222,200);
```

Now, I want to count total number of lines and charge the first 25000 lines 0.15 cents and then remaining 0.10 cents. In future, I will add more quantity and amounts in the AMOUNT table.

So the total lines are 25,900. I want to charge the 25,000 lines 0.15 cents and 900 lines 0.10 cents. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the expected output for your sample data and details of how the expected output is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of aggregation, case expresions and LAG() analytic function like here:

```sql
SELECT  ID, CNT, Sum(CNT_AMOUNT * AMOUNT) "TOTAL"
FROM(   Select  p.ID "ID", p.CNT "CNT",
                CASE  WHEN p.CNT > a.NUM_END 
                      THEN a.NUM_END 
                ELSE p.CNT 
                END - Nvl( LAG(CASE   WHEN p.CNT > a.NUM_END 
                                      THEN a.NUM_END 
                                ELSE p.CNT 
                                END) OVER(Partition By p.ID Order By p.id, a.NUM_START), 0 ) "CNT_AMOUNT",
                a.AMOUNT "AMOUNT"
        FROM    ( Select p.ID "ID", Sum(p.CNT) "CNT"
                  From po p
                  Group By p.ID
                ) p
        Left Join amounts a ON(1 = 1)
    )
Group By ID, CNT
Order By ID, CNT
```

With your sample data (plus ID 30 for testing multiple groups of prices)

```sql
WITH 
    amounts (NUM_START, NUM_END, AMOUNT) AS
        (
            Select 1,     25000,    0.15 From Dual Union All
            Select 25001, 50000,    0.10 From Dual Union All
            Select 50001, 100000,   0.05 From Dual
        ), 

    po (ID, PO_NUM, CNT) AS
        (
            Select 10,  111,    100 From Dual Union All
            Select 10,  222,    500 From Dual Union All
            Select 10,  333,  25000 From Dual Union All
            Select 20,  111,    100 From Dual Union All
            Select 20,  222,    200 From Dual Union All
            Select 30,  111,  53000 From Dual
        )
```

The result is

| ID | CNT | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 25600 | 3810 |
| 20 | 300 | 45 |
| 30 | 53000 | 6400 |

If you want TOTAL of all (without grouping by ID) then:

```sql
SELECT  CNT, Sum(CNT_AMOUNT * AMOUNT) "TOTAL"
FROM    
    (   Select  p.CNT "CNT",
                CASE  WHEN p.CNT > a.NUM_END 
                      THEN a.NUM_END 
                ELSE p.CNT 
                END - Nvl( LAG(CASE   WHEN p.CNT > a.NUM_END 
                                      THEN a.NUM_END 
                                ELSE p.CNT 
                                END) OVER(Order By  a.NUM_START), 0 ) "CNT_AMOUNT", 
                a.AMOUNT "AMOUNT"
        FROM    ( Select Sum(p.CNT) "CNT"
                  From po p
                ) p
        Left Join amounts a ON(1 = 1)
    )
Group By CNT
```

result

| CNT | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| 78900 | 7695 |

Comment: Second row should be 300 *.10 because it has reached over 25,000. We are almost there. I can use your first query in the code only.

Comment: @Manish This is grouped by ID so the ID 20 has 100+200=300. Or do you want it without grouping by ID!? In that case (without group by ID) there will be just one resulting row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytic `SUM` function to find the start and end of each range and then `JOIN` to the `amount` table to get the cost for each part of the range (splitting ranges where they go over the amount boundaries):

```sql
SELECT p.id,
       p.po_num,
       p.cnt,
       GREATEST(p.cnt_start, a.num_start) AS cnt_start,
       LEAST(p.cnt_end, a.num_end) AS cnt_start,
       a.amount,
       a.amount * (LEAST(p.cnt_end, a.num_end) - GREATEST(p.cnt_start, a.num_start) + 1) AS total_cost
FROM   (
         SELECT id,
                po_num,
                cnt,
                SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY po_num) - cnt + 1 AS cnt_start,
                SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY po_num) AS cnt_end
         FROM   po
       ) p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN amount a
       ON a.num_start <= p.cnt_end AND a.num_end >= p.cnt_start
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ID | PO_NUM | CNT | CNT_START | CNT_START | AMOUNT | TOTAL_COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 333 | 25000 | 25001 | 25600 | .1 | 60 |
| 10 | 333 | 25000 | 601 | 25000 | .15 | 3660 |
| 10 | 222 | 500 | 101 | 600 | .15 | 75 |
| 20 | 222 | 200 | 101 | 300 | .15 | 30 |
| 20 | 111 | 100 | 1 | 100 | .15 | 15 |
| 10 | 111 | 100 | 1 | 100 | .15 | 15 |

If you want to aggregate to get the total cost:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.po_num,
       p.cnt,
       SUM(a.amount * (LEAST(p.cnt_end, a.num_end) - GREATEST(p.cnt_start, a.num_start) + 1)) AS total_cost
FROM   (
         SELECT id,
                po_num,
                cnt,
                SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY po_num) - cnt + 1 AS cnt_start,
                SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY po_num) AS cnt_end
         FROM   po
       ) p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN amount a
       ON a.num_start <= p.cnt_end AND a.num_end >= p.cnt_start
GROUP BY
       p.id,
       p.po_num,
       p.cnt;
```

Which outputs:

| ID | PO_NUM | CNT | TOTAL_COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 111 | 100 | 15 |
| 10 | 111 | 100 | 15 |
| 10 | 333 | 25000 | 3720 |
| 10 | 222 | 500 | 75 |
| 20 | 222 | 200 | 30 |

---

If you do not want to `PARTITION BY id` then you can move `id` to the `ORDER BY` clause of the aggregation function:

```sql
SELECT p.id,
       p.po_num,
       p.cnt,
       GREATEST(p.cnt_start, a.num_start) AS cnt_start,
       LEAST(p.cnt_end, a.num_end) AS cnt_start,
       a.amount,
       a.amount * (LEAST(p.cnt_end, a.num_end) - GREATEST(p.cnt_start, a.num_start) + 1) AS total_cost
FROM   (
         SELECT id,
                po_num,
                cnt,
                SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY po_num, id) - cnt + 1 AS cnt_start,
                SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY po_num, id) AS cnt_end
         FROM   po
       ) p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN amount a
       ON a.num_start <= p.cnt_end AND a.num_end >= p.cnt_start
```

Which outputs:

| ID | PO_NUM | CNT | CNT_START | CNT_START | AMOUNT | TOTAL_COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 333 | 25000 | 25001 | 25900 | .1 | 90 |
| 10 | 333 | 25000 | 901 | 25000 | .15 | 3615 |
| 20 | 222 | 200 | 701 | 900 | .15 | 30 |
| 10 | 222 | 500 | 201 | 700 | .15 | 75 |
| 20 | 111 | 100 | 101 | 200 | .15 | 15 |
| 10 | 111 | 100 | 1 | 100 | .15 | 15 |

Or with just the totals:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.po_num,
       p.cnt,
       SUM(a.amount * (LEAST(p.cnt_end, a.num_end) - GREATEST(p.cnt_start, a.num_start) + 1)) AS total_cost
FROM   (
         SELECT id,
                po_num,
                cnt,
                SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY po_num, id) - cnt + 1 AS cnt_start,
                SUM(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY po_num, id) AS cnt_end
         FROM   po
       ) p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN amount a
       ON a.num_start <= p.cnt_end AND a.num_end >= p.cnt_start
GROUP BY
       p.id,
       p.po_num,
       p.cnt;
```

Which outputs:

| ID | PO_NUM | CNT | TOTAL_COST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 111 | 100 | 15 |
| 10 | 111 | 100 | 15 |
| 10 | 333 | 25000 | 3705 |
| 20 | 222 | 200 | 30 |
| 10 | 222 | 500 | 75 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lGDKl-nz)

Comment: @dr No, they all work; its just the OP's question is ambiguous as to what output they expect so there are a couple of (pairs of) answers with different methodology and the expected result depends on how you count the first 25000/50000 rows.

Comment: @MTO Well, it could be either way, I guess. Not sure any more.